# How to compute values for each row (with a unique function) when grouping a data frame in python?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, grouping

I have this pandas data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
         {"CALDT": ["1980-01-31", "1980-02-28", "1980-03-31",
                    "1980-01-31", "1980-02-28", "1980-03-31",
                    "1980-01-31"],
          "ID": [1, 1, 1, 
                 2, 2, 2,
                 3],
          "Return": [0.02, 0.05, 0.10,
                     0.05, -0.02, 0.03,
                     -0.03]
          })

df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CALDT']).dt.year
```

My goal is: If the ID was alive >= 2 months, for each ID and year (grouping), based on `Return`, compute the mean and median multiplied by 12, and assign this value back to the row.

The expected output should look as follows:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(
    {"CALDT": ["1980-01-31", "1980-02-28", "1980-03-31",
               "1980-01-31", "1980-02-28", "1980-03-31",
               "1980-01-31"],
     "Year": [1980, 1980, 1980,
              1980, 1980, 1980,
              1980],
     "ID": [1, 1, 1, 
            2, 2, 2,
            3],
     "Return": [0.02, 0.05, 0.10,
                0.05, -0.02, 0.03,
                0.03],
     "Mean_Return": [0.68, 0.68, 0.68,
                     0.24, 0.24, 0.24,
                     np.nan],
     "Median_Return": [0.60, 0.60, 0.60,
                       0.36, 0.36, 0.36,
                       np.nan]
     })
```

In R, this is quite easy by using `group_by` from `tidyverse`:

```
df = df %>% 
  mutate(Year = year(CALDT)) %>% 
  group_by(CRSP_FUNDNO, Year) %>% 
  mutate(months_alive = length(unique(CALDT))) %>% 
  mutate(mean = case_when(months_alive >= 2 ~ mean(Return)*3,
                          .default = NA)) %>% 
  mutate(median = case_when(months_alive >= 2 ~ mean(Return)*12,
                            .default = NA))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: as a minor detail, last cell of Return becomes +0.03 in the desired output unlike the input of -0.03

Comment: If you are able to work in R fully, then consider using `siuba` instead of `pandas`. Siuba is pandas `tidyverse`. You could directly use `mutate`, `case_when`, `n_distinct` and all are present in siuba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
g = df.groupby(["ID", df.CALDT.dt.year])
return_stats = pd.DataFrame({
                     "Mean_Return": g["Return"].transform("mean").mul(12),
                     "Median_Return": g["Return"].transform("median").mul(12)
                  }).where(g["CALDT"].transform("nunique").ge(2))

df.join(return_stats)
```

- group by the "ID" and the year (we don't have to make a new column to group by)
- calculate desired statistics over "Return", i.e., mean & median, by `transform` (instead of, e.g., `agg`) so that it "broadcasts", i.e., repeats the computed values to be the same size as groups instead of single scalar aggregation
- only retain the stats `where` the *n*umber of *unique* "CALDT" entries per group are *g*reater than or *e*qual to 2
- join this with the original frame

to get

```py
       CALDT  ID  Return  Mean_Return  Median_Return
0 1980-01-31   1    0.02         0.68           0.60
1 1980-02-28   1    0.05         0.68           0.60
2 1980-03-31   1    0.10         0.68           0.60
3 1980-01-31   2    0.05         0.24           0.36
4 1980-02-28   2   -0.02         0.24           0.36
5 1980-03-31   2    0.03         0.24           0.36
6 1980-01-31   3   -0.03          NaN            NaN
```